# How to monitor edited files in a specified folder or hard drive live?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, monitoring

I have a pc running windows 7, and I want a program that monitors my hard drive, giving me reports in real time when files in a specific folder (or on a specific hard drive) are made/moved/changed etc. It would be nice if the program did show a timestamp, and details on which file where wrote.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Monitor hard drive changes to files](http://superuser.com/questions/254557/monitor-hard-drive-changes-to-files), http://superuser.com/questions/438048 ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's an overkill solution but you can use Process Monitor from Windows Sysinternals to actively monitor a specific folder and capture operations such as "CreateFile", "CloseFile" and "QueryDirectory." You can monitor a lot more operations and each in each event you will get the exact timestamp the operation took place. You can configure the operations to capture in the "Filter" menu and also define the path or drive you want to monitor.
You can download Systernal's Process Monitor for free from http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-pt/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx
You can also save the results in multiple formats (CSV, XML) for later analysis